# How to apply different formats to section, subsection, etc

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I searched the internet how to use the titlesec package correctly, but I don't know what to do anymore. I need to format the headings as stated in the attached picture, but nothing I try is working. Below is the best I achieved, but this way the first level doesnt have a number and the second level isn't even visible. I appreciate any help.

```
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\Large\bfseries\center\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}
```

[image: Formating requirements]

Comment: Instead of search the internet did you read the `titlesec` manual? You probably already have it on your computer, otherwise see http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/titlesec/titlesec.pdf

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You're missing `{#1}` as the last argument for subsections (since you load the `explicit` option).